# LIMIT equivalent for SQL Server 2012 in an UPDATE statement

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I have the following table below and am trying to update the first available row with an user ID through a query, but I need to limit this to only update one row and not multiple.

```
ID     Model     UserID
1      X12T5     1
2      X13T5     2
3      X14T5     NULL
4      X15T5     NULL
```

The first available row would be where ID is 3. I would update it with the following query:

```
UPDATE Table SET UserID = '3' WHERE UserID IS NULL
```

But I want to make sure it affects only 1 row and not multiple that are available, LIMIT doesn't exist in SQL Server.

What would the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this with `UPDATE TOP`. It's the equivalent of a `SELECT TOP` but for updates; and `TOP` is SQL Server's equivalent of MySQL's `LIMIT`.

See [further info](http://sqlmag.com/t-sql/more-top-troubles-using-top-insert-update-and-delete).

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE Table SET UserID = '3'
WHERE UserID IS NULL
 AND Id IN (SELECT top 1 ID FROM table where UserId IS NULL)
```

Comment: No ORDER BY needed in the sub-query?

Answer (score 0):

You can also use any of the following methods (Assuming column ID is of integer datatype)

Using `subquery` :

```
UPDATE a
SET a.UserID='3'
FROM YourTable a
 WHERE ID =( SELECT MIN(ID)
FROM YourTable 
WHERE UserID is NULL)
```

Using `JOIN`:

```
UPDATE a
SET a.UserID='3'
FROM YourTable a
 JOIN 
 ( SELECT MIN(ID) MinId
   FROM YourTable 
   WHERE UserID is NULL) b
    ON a.ID=b.MinId
```

Using `CTE`

```
WITH cte_a
AS
(SELECT MIN(ID) MinId
   FROM YourTable 
   WHERE UserID is NULL)
UPDATE a
SET a.UserID='3'
FROM YourTable a
 JOIN cte_a b a.ID=b.MinId
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [CTE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx) & perform the `SELECT\UPDATE\DELETE` operations ,

```
; WITH CTE AS (
SELECT TOP 10 * FROM TABLE
)
UPDATE CTE 
SET ...
```

`DELETE\UPDATE\SELECT` works with CTE ... Cool !!!